# React-Native Mobx remove item

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobx

How can I remove an item from an array in Mobx observable?

This is the observable:

```
@persist('list') @observable eventos = []
```

This is how I add an item to the list:

```
  @action addEvento (id, title) {
    this.eventos.push({
      id: id,
      nome: title,
    })
  }
```

and this is what I've tried to remove it:

```
  @action removeEvento (id, title) {
    var i = this.eventos.indexOf(id);
    console.log(i)
    if(i != -1) {
      this.eventos.splice(i, 1)
      return this.eventos
    }
  }
```

But it always removes the last item added, instead of the item that I want to remove. Also, indexOf always returns -1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to find the index of the element with value `id`, but you want to find where the object's `id` is equal to `id`.

You could e.g. use a filter and replace instead:

```
@action removeEvento (id, title) {
  var filteredEventos = this.eventos.filter(evento => evento.id !== id);
  this.eventos.replace(filteredEventos);
}
```

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense! And the code works perfectly :) Thank you!

Comment: @waze Great! No problem. :)